# ESP32 HTTP.GET() return -1 and -11

Tags: c, http, wifi, esp32

I am working with ESP32, everything is working fine but when I want to make POST or even GET request I get -1 status or sometimes 11.

I tried things like :

- on the other server - http/https - GET/POST- didnt work out
  I'm crashed here :(

```
#ifdef ESP32
  #include <WiFi.h>
  #include <HTTPClient.h>
#else
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
  #include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
  #include <WiFiClient.h>
#endif

#include <Wire.h>


// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid     = "XXXXX";
const char* password = "XXXXX";

void setup() {
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(4000);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
 
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
 
}
 
void loop() {
 
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { //Check the current connection status
 
    HTTPClient http;
 
    http.begin("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?id=10");
    //Specify the URL
    int httpCode = http.GET();                                        //Make the request
    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code
 
        String payload = http.getString();
        Serial.println(httpCode);
        Serial.println(payload);
      }
 
    else {
      Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
    }
 
    http.end(); //Free the resources
  }
 
  delay(10000);
 
}
```

Comment: doesn't the site use https?